# How to install Octave on rhel fedora based Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, octave, fedora, rhel

How to install Octave on Amazon EC2 instance? The configuration of the EC2 instance is as follows:

[image]

First, I created a tmp directory and downloaded the EPEL rpm in the tmp directory and installed the EPEL repository with the commands:

[image]

I tried to use the following command (please see the following website for more details about this command [link for more details of the command](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/EEGLAB_and_supercomputing_applications_using_free_alternatives_to_Matlab)) to install Octave, but it was not working (see the following result):

[image]

Also, I tried to enable the package by changing "enabled = 0" to "enabled = 1" in the file "/etc/yum.repos.d", and used yum to install octave, but it was still not working. The error message is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to use the command to test it (see below for more details):

[image]

I am not sure if some package management tools (e.g., subscription-manager, dnf) to handle the dependency issues. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Octave is a programming language — doesn't that fall under "software tools commonly used by programmer"?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux is based on RHEL and Fedora, but is *not* RHEL or Fedora. Fedora EPEL is made on RHEL and will also work on CentOS and other rebuilds which aim to be *just like RHEL*. It looks like you are hitting an area where Amazon Linux is different. Your options are:

1. Rebuild all of those missing packages on Amazon Linux
2. Install Octave and all dependencies from source rather than RPM
3. Use RHEL, Fedora, or CentOS